# Ajax Livesearch search in two colums

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, livesearch

I use the ajax livesearch from here: [Ajax Livesearch](http://ajaxlivesearch.com/)

I want to let users search for cities in the database and it works perfectly so far.
When I type a letter it will show me the cities and the zipcode.
Now I try to make the same searchbox also work using a cypher so that the cities will be shown if the user search by zipcodes.
But I am stuck completely. Maybe some one has some experience with searchboxes and can help me out.

In the `config.php` i defined the search column:

```
const USER_TABLE = 'cities';
const SEARCH_COLUMN = 'Name';
```

To get the results from the database I have this:

```
$db = DB::getConnection();

    // get the number of total result
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ' . Config::USER_TABLE . ' WHERE ' . Config::SEARCH_COLUMN . ' LIKE :query');
    $search_query = $query.'%';
    $stmt->bindParam(':query', $search_query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $number_of_result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    // initialize variables
    $HTML = '';
    $number_of_pages = 1;

    if ( (int) $number_of_result !== 0)
    {
        if ($items_per_page === 0)
        {
            // show all
            $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . Config::USER_TABLE . ' WHERE ' . Config::SEARCH_COLUMN . ' LIKE :query ORDER BY ' .Config::SEARCH_COLUMN);
            $search_query = $query.'%';
            $stmt->bindParam(':query', $search_query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        else
        {
            /*
             * pagination
             *
             * calculate total pages
             */
            if ($number_of_result < $items_per_page)
                $number_of_pages = 1;
            elseif ($number_of_result > $items_per_page)
                $number_of_pages = floor($number_of_result / $items_per_page) + 1;
            else
                $number_of_pages = $number_of_result / $items_per_page;

            /*
             * pagination
             *
             * calculate start
             */
            $start = ($current_page > 0 ) ? ($current_page - 1) * $items_per_page : 0;

            $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . Config::USER_TABLE . ' WHERE ' . Config::SEARCH_COLUMN . ' LIKE :query ORDER BY '.Config::SEARCH_COLUMN.' LIMIT ' . $start . ', ' . $items_per_page);
            $search_query = $query.'%';
            $stmt->bindParam(':query', $search_query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        // run the query and get the result
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And this will show the results on my site:

```
foreach($results as $result)
        {
            $HTML .= "<tr><td>{$result['Name']}</td><td>{$result['Postal_Code']}</td></tr>";
        }
```

So if I type the letters it will also give me the right zipcode from the column 'Postal_Code'.
But I guess it is also possible to do it the other way, I type the number and it shows me the city and the zip?
In the `config.php` i can only one column define

```
const SEARCH_COLUMN = 'Name';
```

Maybe it's possible to use a second const like:

```
const SEARCH_COLUMN2 = 'Postal_Code';
```

?
But how can I use it in the db query than?
 It's a bit difficult for me to explain my problem so I hope you will understand me any way :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you add another constant to your config, you could then just add an `OR` clause to your query:

```
' WHERE ' . Config::SEARCH_COLUMN . ' LIKE :query OR '. Config::SEARCH_COLUMN2 . ' LIKE :query'
```

Comment: doesn't matter what i try. it won't work :(
is there a wy to add a second column to a constant?